Find records from column one if all the values in column 2 have a same value
I want to get records in column one and two, but only those which have all the same value ( LIKE %ABGS% ) in column 3.
We have in Col1 a group of IDs, these Ids can have in Col 2 1...N entries and for each entries in combination of column Col 1 and Col 2 different values in column 3. So The groups are Col 1 with Col 2 and different values in Col 3.
As a result I want to have only the result of Col1 and Col2 which have all the same values in Col 3 (LIKE %ABGS%). If one of the entries under the group Col1 and Col2 don't have this status, it must be excluded from the result!
In the tables below you can hopefully understand the scope of my request
Table:



Col 1
Col 2
Col 3




PSPID_1
POSID_10
FREI ABGS EROF


PSPID_1
POSID_11
ABGS EROF


PSPID_1
POSID_12
FREI ABGS


PSPID_2
PSPID_20
FREI ABGS


PSPID_2
PSPID_21
EROF


PSPID_3
POSID_30
ABGS EROF


PSPID_3
POSID_31
ABGS EROF


PSPID_3
POSID_32
FREI ABGS EROF


PSPID_3
POSID_33
FREI ABGS



The result should be:



Col 1
Col 2




PSPID_1
POSID_10


PSPID_1
POSID_11


PSPID_1
POSID_12


PSPID_3
POSID_30


PSPID_3
POSID_31


PSPID_3
POSID_32


PSPID_3
POSID_33




In Col 2 POSID_10, POSID_11, POSID_12 are under PSPID_1 in Col 1 and all the values in Col3 have LIKE %ABGS% --> Include in the result

In Col 2 POSID_20, POSID_21 are under PSPID_2 in Col 1 and not all the values in Col3 have LIKE %ABGS% --> Exclude from the result

In Col 2 POSID_30, POSID_31, POSID_32,POSID_33 are under PSPID_3 in Col 1 and all the values in Col3 have LIKE %ABGS% --> Include in the result


The data are clustered like this:








PSPID_1


- POSID_10


- POSID_11


- POSID_12


PSPID_2


- POSID_20


- POSID_21


PSPID_3


- POSID_30


- POSID_31


- POSID_32


- POSID_33


PSPID_4


- POSID_40


- POSID_41



Etc.....

Seems like you should be fixing your design, and you should have one row per value in Column3, not a space delimited value.

What query have you tried and what were the results? How did those compare to your defined specification?

The answers so far assume you are only interested in a specific value ABGS. Are you looking for a more generic solution that selects groups where all of the col 3 values share at least one (arbitrary) token value? For example, if all of the PSPID_3 rows had FOO in place of ABGS, would you still want that group selected? Also, can we assume that the col 2 values are distinct. Can we also assume that there are no duplicates within in col 3. (A solution would likely involve splitting and counting. Duplicates would complicate the logic.)

One method would be to get the number of rows in the group and how many rows fit the criteria using windowed COUNTs, and then filtering on when those values are the same (and greater than 1). This results in the following:
DECLARE @SearchValue varchar(4) = 'ABGS';

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT YT.Column1,
           YT.Column2,
           YT.Column3,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.Column1) AS TotalRows,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN YT.Column3 LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.Column1) AS SearchRows
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT)
SELECT CTE.Column1,
       CTE.Column2
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.TotalRows = CTE.SearchRows
  AND CTE.SearchRows > 0;


Alternatively just COUNT(CASE WHEN YT.Column3 NOT LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.Column1) AS SearchRows and WHERE SearchRows = 0 seems simpler


filtered_groups CTE will get all the unique col1 where col3 matches the given string, HAVING count(*) ensures that all rows within each col1 group must contain 'ABGS' in col3.

Once required col1 are found, col2 is fetched by joining the original table


Fiddle
WITH filtered_groups AS (
    SELECT col1
    FROM test
    GROUP BY col1
    HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN col3 LIKE '%ABGS%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)
SELECT t.col1, t.col2
FROM test t
JOIN filtered_groups fg ON t.col1 = fg.col1
ORDER BY t.col1, t.col2;

Output



col1
col2




PSPID_1
POSID_10


PSPID_1
POSID_11


PSPID_1
POSID_12


PSPID_3
POSID_30


PSPID_3
POSID_31


PSPID_3
POSID_32


PSPID_3
POSID_33




You can resolve it with a left self-join where the left-hand side would be the records you are interested about and the right-hand-side would be undesirable matches. Where no undesirable matches exist, there are the results:
select desirable.[Col 1],
       desirable.[Col 2]
from t desirable
left join t undesirable
on desirable.[Col 1] = undesirable.[Col 1] and undesirable.[Col 3] not like '%ABGS%'
where desirable.[Col 3] like '%ABGS%'; and undesirable.[Col 1] is null
group by desirable.[Col 1], desirable.[Col 2]

Explanation:

I presumed your table name is t, change it to the actual name
We self-join t and we consider the left-hand side desirable
We filter desirable by they being like the pattern you specified to exclude first-class mismatches
We do a left join t and alias it as undesirable to see whether any mismatch for this [Col 1] value exists
If such a second-class mismatch is found, then we ignore this [Col 1] value
For the values which were passing the criteria, we group by [Col 1] and [Col 2] to get rid of any duplicates
We select the fields that interest us


If you need to find groups where all rows contain the same arbitrary token (not limited to ABGS), the following approach can be used:

Count the number of rows for each Col 1 value.
Split the Col 3 values into tokens and count the number of occurrences for each Col 1 and token value combination.
Extract a distinct list of Col 1 values where the two counts match.
Join the selected Col 1 values back to the original data.

WITH SelectedCol1Values AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT D.Col1
    FROM (
        SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Col1) AS Col1GroupCount
        FROM Data D
    ) D
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(D.col3, ' ') S
    GROUP BY D.Col1, D.Col1GroupCount, S.value
    HAVING COUNT(*) = D.Col1GroupCount
)
SELECT D.Col1, D.Col2
FROM SelectedCol1Values S
JOIN Data D
    ON D.Col1 = S.Col1

This assumes that each Col2 value is unique withing each Col1 group. It also assumed that the tokens are unique withing each Col3 value.
Intermediate results (with some modified test data):



Col1
Col1GroupCount
value
Col3ItemCount
Match




PSPID_1
3
ABGS
3
Match


PSPID_1
3
EROF
2



PSPID_1
3
FREI
2



PSPID_2
2
ABGS
1



PSPID_2
2
EROF
1



PSPID_2
2
FREI
1



PSPID_3
4
EROF
3



PSPID_3
4
FREI
2



PSPID_3
4
WXYZ
4
Match



Final results:



Col1
Col2




PSPID_1
POSID_10


PSPID_1
POSID_11


PSPID_1
POSID_12


PSPID_3
POSID_30


PSPID_3
POSID_31


PSPID_3
POSID_32


PSPID_3
POSID_33



If Col3 values might contain duplicate tokens, you can change the HAVING condition to HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT D.Col2) = D.Col1GroupCount, so that each row is only counted once. If the Col2 value might be duplicated withing a Col1 group, you can use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to assign distinct row IDs that can then be used in in place of Col2.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
